# How can I make this regex shorter?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote this regex:

```
\\s+(?:([^:]+):)(?:([^:]+):)(?:([^:]+):)(?:([^:]+):)
```

to parse such things:

lvt:vgt:mwi-ao:44.00m::::lvt_mlog:100.00:
  lvt2:vgt2:-wi-a-:908.00m::::::

And

1 group will be: lvt
2 group: vgt
...
4 group:  44.00m

I whant to make it shorter.

I try to do it in such way: `\\s+(?:([^:]+):)+`

But in this case it catch only last group.

Result will be:
1 group:  44.00m

Comment: Are you using the `.match()` or the `.find()`?

Comment: Why are there `:` in the groups if there are no `:` in the text to match? Besides that, if you want to catch every of the 4 groups, AFAIK there's no way to shorten that expression in Java.

Comment: I pasted incorrect text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary non-capturing parentheses that you can remove:

```
\\s+([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+):
```

Comment: Please note that unless the text to match starts with whitespace, using `\\s+` won't match `lvt` etc. You might want to use `(?:^|\\s+)` instead.

Comment: @Thomas: You're right - but it seems his regex is already working, he just wants to make it shorter. Also, `\s*` would do instead of `(?:^|\\s+)`.

Comment: It seems so, maybe he has whitespace at the start. Btw, you can make it even shorter by removing the last colon :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't catch multiple matches into a single group, i.e. can't use `(?:([^:]+):)+` to collect `lvt`, `vgt` etc. into a single group in one go.

What you could do is break the text into individual lines and if you know there are always 4 groups, call `find()` and then `group(0)` 4 times in a row using an expression like this: `[^:]+`. This should catch `lvt`, `vgt`, `mwi-ao` and `44.00m` in 4 calls.

Some pseudocode (not tested, so it might contain typos :) ):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^:]+");

String input = ...;
String[] lines = input.split("\\s");

for( String line : lines ) {
  //note that for simple cases like above you could also just split by ":"

  Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
  List<String> elements = new LinkedList<String>();
  while( m.find() ) {
    elements.add( m.group(0) );
  }

  //get the first 4 elements from the list
  //if there are less then 4 in the list, the line didn't match
}
```

**Edit**: I updated the answer to match the edited question which seems to delimit "lines" my whitespace and fields by colons (`:`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for values between ':' you can use String.split(regex)

```
String[] result = 
   "lvt:vgt:mwi-ao:44.00m::::lvt_mlog:100.00: lvt2:vgt2:-wi-a-:908.00m::::::".split(":");
```

If it is convenient for you, it would be faster than group regex ... and it *is the shorter regex* you can find

*EDIT erroneous annotation suppressed 

Add group*

Groups are found like this if regular '`::::`' :

```
for(int i = 0, n = result.length; i < n; i+= 6) {
    final String group1 = result[i];
    final String group2  =result[i+1];
    ...
}
```

else use `while` and restart to group1 after last empty field.

Comment: No, `split()` won't remove all empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class RegexTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern pat= Pattern.compile("\\s(([^:]+):){3}([^:]+)");
        Matcher mat= pat.matcher(" lvt:vgt:mwi-ao:44.00m::::lvt_mlog:100.00: lvt2:vgt2:-wi-a-:908.00m::::::");
        while(mat.find()){
            System.console().format("group: %s , start: %d , end: %d\\n",
            mat.group(), mat.start(), mat.end());
        }
    }
}
```

> group:  lvt:vgt:mwi-ao:44.00m , start: 0 , end: 22
>
> group:  lvt2:vgt2:-wi-a-:908.00m , start: 42 , end: 67

You can then split the groups by ':'